# How to find duplicates in a column in a datatable and make them with a star asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I have a in-memory `DataTable` and I need to mark the duplicates ..... for example ..

From
[image]
To 
[image]

I would probably do something like ..

```
    For each dtrow in dt.rows
    If dtrow("Country") Is one of Duplicates then
            dtrow("Country") += "*"
    end if
    Next
```

Sorry for asking so many questions ... My head is burnt .. nothing came out .. and this project is needing to finish very soon ..

Comment: What results do you get trying the above? I would think you'd have to access the value of the column, not the column name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `LINQ-to-DataTable`:

```
Dim dups = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
           Let country = row.Field(Of String)("Country")
           Group row By country Into DupCountries = Group
           Where DupCountries.Count() > 1
           Select DupCountries
For Each dupCountryRows In dups
    For Each row In dupCountryRows
        row("Country") = row.Field(Of String)("Country") & "*"
    Next
Next
```

Or with C# syntax:

```
var dups = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
           let id = row.Field<string>("Country")
           group row by country
           into DupCountries where DupCountries.Count() > 1
           select DupCountries;
```