# Group By Multiple columns and count it

Tags: vb.net

I have a list (`sourceList`), for example:

```
id      price1    price2    Data
---------------------------------
12       88        222        1
12       88        222        4
12       66        234        4
```

I need to group it by all the three columns: `id`, `price1`, `price2`.

There is no meaning for the column `Data`.

I need to get this new list:

```
id    numOfAds    price1    price2
----------------------------------
12       2          88        222   -> 2 cause there are two simmilar ads with the same price 1 and 2
12       1          66        234
```

so I tried:

```
Dim oResult = sourceList.GroupBy(Function(v) New With 
              {Key v.id, Key v.price1, Key v.price2}).ToList()
```

But I don't know how to count the equal rows..

**EDITED:**

Maybe something like this one?

```
Dim sums = sourceList.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {Key x.id, Key 
            x.price1, Key x.price2}) _
            .Select(Function(group) New With {Key .Peo = group, Key .NumOfAds = group.Count()})
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure about what you trying to achieve. Do you want to count the rows with same values?

Comment: @Dura, Yes.. the output list should contain the id, price1 and price2 and the 4-th column should be the count of the rows that equal in these parameters (id, price1, price2).. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be the `New with` statements.

Try this

```
Dim sums = sourceList.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("YourField")).Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key)
```

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600550/how-to-find-duplicates-in-a-column-in-a-datatable-and-make-them-with-a-star-asp) might also be helpful for what you need.